# Comparing user input with text in a file

Tags: c

The below code can output what is inside my file. I am trying to find a way to compare if the user input word/character is included in the text file. For instance, if the user writes "r" then, the program finds all the words that have an "r" in the file and output them.  After that, I want to replace this word with something, so instead of "r", make it "k". For example, "roadtrip" --> "koadtrip".

The text file has a lot of words line by line , a screenshot of a small part[image]

```
#define MAX 1024
int main() {


 FILE* myFile = fopen("C:\\Users\\Luther\\Desktop\\txtfiles\\words.txt", "r+");
    char inputWord[MAX];
    char lineBuffer[MAX];
if (myFile1 == NULL)
{


printf("File Does Not Exist \n");
        return 1;
}

printf("Enter the word \n");
fgets(inputWord, MAX, stdin);
while (!feof(myFile1))
{
    char lineBuffer[1024];
    fscanf(myFile1, "%1024[^\n]\n", lineBuffer);
    //printf("%s\n", lineBuffer);
    while (fgets(lineBuffer, MAX, myFile)) {
        if (strstr(lineBuffer, inputWord))
            puts(lineBuffer);


    }
}
```

}

I 've managed to make it work and now the program outputs regarding the user input. If a  word is the same or part of it is found in the text file, then it prints the word. Look the screenshot below:

Now I am looking for a way to replace the word. For instance, in this specific situation, the word the user inputted is "es" and then all the words that have "es" as a part of them are printed. Is there a way that I can replace for all occasions the "es" and make it "er". Then save the changes in another file without changing anything in the original file. 
[image]

Comment: [Edit]  your question and show a [MCVE] as well as a minimal example of your text file, an example of user input, the expected output and finally the actual output (if any). Also read this: [ask]. Remainder: this site is not a free code writing service. Instead we are here to help you with problems in thbge code you have written.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the `strcmp` function or maybe `strchr`. But without more information it's hard to help.

Comment: Like a [compact prefix trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree), or can it be any substring?

Comment: it can be any substring.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to use as a start:

```
    #define _GNU_SOURCE
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <assert.h>

    int main (int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        FILE    *fp      = fopen(argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "/etc/motd", "r");
        char    *line    = NULL;
        char    *p       = NULL;
        char    *needle  = argv[2];
        char    *replace = argv[3];
        size_t   len     = 0;
        ssize_t  read;
        assert(fp);

        while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
            if (line[0] != '#') {
                if ((p = strstr(line, needle))) {
                    printf("%.*s%s%s", (int)(p - line), line, replace, p+strlen(replace));
                } else {
                    printf("%s", line);
                }
            }
        }

        free(line);
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }
```

Note: this may not handle all edge cases. Also writing back to a file or renaming to
original is left as an exercise :)

Comment: I am struggling to understand your code, I am not very familiar with the int argc and char argv [ ]  as parameters. Hence, I am not sure if I can follow what are you suggesting.  I will try to read find smth to help me understand and I will come back tto work on it. Thank you

Comment: @ImSkilzBTW, its just the file name and the strings to find and replace - all of these are reads from `argv[1]`, `argv[2]` and `argv[3]` respectively. You could as well replace them with `scanf`. In this case, the program will be run as `./a.out /path/to/file  abc def` (to replace `abc` with `def`). HTH

Answer (score 0):

Some other starting point

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<regex.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

int main (){
    //open file
    FILE *file_pointer = fopen("./test_txt.txt", "r");
    const char* search_for = "3_hau_gbs";

    int line_number = 1;
    char* line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;


    regex_t regex;
    int failed = regcomp(&regex, search_for, REG_EXTENDED);
    //You are serching bitwise, so you must first semicompile it
    if(failed){
        regfree(&regex);
    } else {
        while(getline(&line, &len, file_pointer) != -1){
            //go line after line and check if it include the word you 
            //you are looking for
            int match = regexec(&regex, line, 0, NULL, 0);
            if(!match){
                //when find so output
                printf("%d:%s",line_number, line);
            }
            line_number++;
        }
        if(line){
            free(line);
        }
        regfree(&regex);
        fclose(file_pointer);
    }
  }
```